# A largest subset of a cubic lattice with unique distances between its points

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-geometry

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Consider a set $S_n=([1,n]\cap\mathbb N)^3$ having $n^3$ points in the Euclidean space $\mathbb R^3$ arranged in a cubic lattice. Let $a_n$ be the size of a largest subset of $S_n$ such that for each pair of points in the subset there are no other pair of points in the subset having the same distance between them (i.e. all distances between points in the subset are unique).
[image: Example for n = 3]
Can you suggest an efficient way to compute $a_n$, or find a general formula for this sequence? Or, at least, find $a_n$ for a few small positive integers?

---

*Update:* Lower or upper bounds, or asymptotic behavior are welcome. Is the sequence $\{a_n\}$ strictly increasing?

---

*Update:* The corresponding OEIS sequence: [$A275672$](https://oeis.org/A275672) (only terms $n=0..6$ are currently known).

Comment: I would expect this to be very difficult. Even in the one-dimensional case, where the constraint leads to the so called [Golomb's ruler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golomb_ruler), these are open questions. Anyway, a trivial upper bound for $a_n$ comes from the observation that the squared distances are integers in the range $[1,3(n-1)^2]$, so we get the bound
$$\binom{a_n}2\le 3(n-1)^2.$$ Of course, it may turn out that 3D is easier.

Comment: A tiny sharpening to the bound above comes from the fact that not all integers are sums of three squares. We can leave out of reckoning as squared distances the integers that are $\equiv7\pmod8$ and those gotten from these by multiplying them with a power of four. This is [the Three-Square Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem). We can also leave out those integers in the range $[1,3(n-1)^2]$ that require squares larger than $(n-1)^2$. Bounds: $a_2\le 3, a_3\le4, a_4\le6$. The first two are tight, but I don't want to find $a_4$ by trial and error.

Answer (score 10):

For each $r \in [1, \ldots, 3 n^2]$ let $E_r$ be the set of unordered pairs $(p,q)$ of points in $S_n$ such that $\|p-q\|^2 = r$.  We want a largest possible subset $X$ of $S_n$ such that $X$ contains at most one of each $E_r$.
It can be considered as a quadratically constrained integer programming problem:

maximize $\sum_{p \in S_n} x_p$

subject to $\sum_{(p,q) \in S_r} x_p x_q \le 1$ for each $r$

all $x_p \in \{0,1\}$

Not that there are efficient methods to solve this, but CPLEX ought to be able to do this for small $n$.

EDIT:  It appears that a careful integer linear programming model (with binary variables for both edges and vertices) works better. The results for small $n$ are

$$ \matrix{n & a_n\cr
           1 & 1\cr
           2 & 3\cr
           3 & 4\cr
           4 & 6\cr}$$
I have some faint hopes of getting $a_5$ (so far CPLEX has found a solution with $7$ vertices and an upper bound of $19.51$)

EDIT:  CPLEX crashed before obtaining an optimal solution for $n=5$.
An example to show $a_5 \ge 7$ is 
$$\pmatrix{     3  &   4  &   2\cr
     1  &   2  &   2\cr
     4  &   4  &   2\cr
     5 &   5   &  2\cr
     5  &   1  &   4\cr
     5  &   5  &   4\cr
     2  &   1  &   5\cr}$$

EDIT:

For $n=6$, Jyrki's estimate shows $a_6 \le 9$, and (using tabu search) I was able to find an example to show $a_6 = 9$:

$$ \pmatrix{   4  &   3 &    1\cr
     1  &   5  &   4\cr
     1  &   2  &   6\cr
     6  &   1  &   1\cr
     1  &   6  &   4\cr
     2  &   5  &   3\cr
     2  &   2  &   2\cr
     6  &   2  &   6\cr
     1  &   6  &   6\cr}$$

EDIT: I was able to find an example to show $a_7 \ge 10$:
$$\pmatrix{
    1  &   7  &   7\cr
     5 &    7  &   1\cr
     7 &    2  &   2\cr
     7 &    5  &   5\cr
     1 &    2  &   2\cr
     1 &    4  &   7\cr
     2 &    7  &   7\cr
     7 &    6  &   4\cr
     1 &    7  &   5\cr
     6 &    3  &   1\cr}$$

Still trying for $11$.

Comment: I found that $a_5=7$ by exhaustive search. There are $4223$ distinct $7$-point configurations (up to rotation and reflection), and none of them can be extended to $8$ points.

Answer (score 8):

Promoting the comments to an answer, as the upper bound seems to be surprisingly good early on.

We want to avoid repetitions of squared distances. The squared distance $d$ between two points in $S_n$ is of the form
$$
d=a^2+b^2+c^2,
$$
where $a,b,c$ are integers in the range $[0,n-1]$. Let us denote by $D_n$
the set of such sums $>0$. The exact size of the set $D_n$ is difficult to write down, but it is obviously $<3(n-1)^2$, and does grow roughly as a quadratic polynomial function of $n$.

Call a subset $S\subseteq S_n$ a *3-dimensional Golomb ruler*, 3DGR for short, if there are no repetitions among the squared distances between its points. If $S$ is a 3DGR with $m$ elements, then the squared distances between its points form a subset of $\binom m2$ integers of the set $D_n$. Hence we have the inequality
$$
\binom m2\le |D_n|.\qquad(*)
$$
So if $a_n$ is the maximum size of a 3DGR $S\subseteq S_n$, then
we have an upper bound $a_n\le m$, where $m$ is the largest integer satisfying $(*)$.

---

Example. Consider the case $n=3$. We see easily that the set $D_3$ consists of integers
$$
D_3=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,12\},
$$
a total of nine elements. Because $\binom 42<9<\binom 52$ we can deduce that a 3DGR $\subseteq S_3$ can have at most four elements. It is easy to check that
$$
S=\{(1,1,1),(1,1,3),(2,3,3),(3,3,3)\}
$$
is a 3DGR (yielding the squared distances $1,4,5,8,9,12$). Therefore the bound is tight in this case, and we can conclude that $a_3=4$.

---

Here's a short table (thanks, Mathematica) of the upper bounds to $a_n$:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|ccc|c|c}
n&|D_n|&a_n\le&&n&|D_n|&a_n\le\\
\hline
1&0&1&&11&178&19\\
2&3&3&&12&211&21\\
3&9&4&&13&259&23\\
4&18&6&&14&299&24\\
5&31&8&&15&346&26\\
6&44&9&&16&401&28\\
7&66&12&&17&463&30\\
8&87&13&&18&516&32\\
9&115&15&&19&591&34\\
10&144&17&&20&648&36
\end{array}
$$

So we see that the upper bound grows linearly as a function of $n$ (follows immediately from the estimates on the size of $D_n$). I dare not guess, how the true values of $a_n$ behave. The case of [1-dimensional Golomb rulers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golomb_ruler) is difficult enough, and huge amounts of computing resources have been put towards improving their construction.

Comment: Thanks! Is the sequence $\{a_n\}$ strictly increasing?

Comment: I don't know @VladimirReshetnikov :-( It shouldn't be too difficult to prove that the upper bound is strictly increasing, but I'm afraid I have no intuition about how tight the bound is.